# Map Reduce Python 3.x- TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'function'

Tags: python

Taking a data science class and this is the textbook example, but I can't translate it into python 3.x.

---

```
import sys

def mapper():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = line.split(',')
        print (data[1] + ',' + data[2])
    
def reduce():
    high = 0

    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = line.split(',')
        close = float(data[1].rstrip())
    
    if (close > high):
        high = close
        date = data[0]
        
    print(date + ',' + str(high))

path = r'C:\Users\kingj\Downloads\stocks.csv'

mapper < path | reduce
```

---

I get this error:

```
----> 2 mapper < path | reduce

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'function'
```

Comment: `mapper < path | reduce` is not Python syntax; it's more like shell syntax.  I guess these idea is that you compile these two functions into their own executables so you can pipe `path` into `mapper` and then pipe the resulting output into `reduce`.  If the textbook didn't explain how to do this, it's not a good textbook IMO.

Comment: yeah doesn't look like python syntax to me either.  its' not multithreading method , reduce doesn't return anything to even pipe and then using comparison operand with mapper doean't make sense

Comment: Here's more info on shell redirections and pipes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe